# I am confused about the definition of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused about the following definition:

[image: Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra, page 337]

I was always taught that with a group action, we have $e.m=m$ but then from this property $(2a)$ we would have $m=(e+e).m=e.m+e.m=m+m=2m$ for all $m$. What am I missing?

Comment: How does $m = (e + e) . m$?

Comment: because $m=e.m=(e+e).m$

Comment: You are suffering from a case of brain-fart (nothing shameful, very common in math). Think again about why on earth $m$ should be equal to $(e+e)m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't say "group action", it just says action. It later defines what exactly is meant by an "action" in this context.

Comment: Did you also see this and immediately know it was from Dummit and Foote? I was going to say the exact same thing.

Comment: No, I didn't get that far with D&F. But It's a really good book. But the picture contains the fragment where the author explains what is meant by an action. ( A map from $R\times M$ to $M$ satisfying certaing properties).

Comment: oh OK I am sorry, I didn't even realize. So we do not have the property $e.m=m$?

Comment: @tmpys By $e$ do you mean the identity element of a group? There is no group mentioned in this definition.

Comment: @stewbasic If the ring has a multiplicative identity then the condition $1m=m$ must hold. It is also easy to show that the other conditions imply $0m=0$ for all $m$

Comment: I meant the additive identity of the ring, but I now realize I was being silly to assume the group action property and also that if that property held, that it would be the additive identity. I understand now. Thanks and sorry for wasting all your time.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: apologies! I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: @RobArthan no problems, if only I had a nickel for everytime is happened to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confusing the multiplicative identity $1$ in $R$ with the additive identity $0.$

For $em=m,$ $e$ should be the multiplicative identity $1.$

However, in $e+e=e,$ $\;e$ refers to the additive identity $0.$

Answer (score 0):

Property 2a says $(e+e)m = em + em$.  Apply the property with $r=s=e$.